# How to rewrite if-else statements better in python

Tags: python, if-statement, switch-statement, dry

I have some if-else statement like below, basically it works like charm, but the conditions're changed frequently, it can add more,.... So I think if-else way isn't optimize. That's why I wonder if there are a better solution to reduce code duplicated for that.

```
name1, name2, name3, name4, name5 =   "David", "Luke", "Kate", "Bobby", "Megan"
sentences = ["Megan is my friend", "Boddy is my friend"]
existed_name = []
for sentence in sentences:
    if name1 in sentence:
        existed_name.append(name1)
    elif name2 in sentence:
        existed_name.append(name2)
    elif name3 in sentence:
        existed_name.append(name3)
    elif name4 in sentence:
        existed_name.append(name4)
    elif name5 in sentence:
        existed_name.append(name5)
    else: 
        existed_name.append('Empty')
```

Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: Always append name1?

Comment: Okay, so. You know how you use `for sentence in sentences:` in order to *do the same thing with* each of the `sentence` values that is `in sentences`? So, here you have a bunch of names that you want to *do the same thing with*. Can you think of a better way to organize them, that would then let you use the same technique? (Hint: what is the type of `sentences`? What if you made another one of those, and put the names in it?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to Abhinav's answer, you can have a flag to see if the name existed or not.

```
names = ["David", "Luke", "Kate", "Bobby", "Megan"]
sentences = ["Megan is my friend", "Boddy is my friend"]

for sentence in sentences:
    existed = False
    for name in names:
        if name in sentence:
            existed_name.append(name)
            existed = True
            break

    if not existed:
        existed_name.append("Empty")
```

Comment: I think you need `break` to prevent unneeded comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple nested loop for this if you define all the names in a single list instead of as separate variables.

```py
names = ["David", "Luke", "Kate", "Bobby", "Megan"]
sentences = ["Megan is my friend", "Boddy is my friend"]
existing_names = []
for sentence in sentences:
    for name in names:
        if name in sentence:
            existing_names.append(name)
            
print(existing_names)
# ["Megan"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer one liner list comprehension

```
names =   ["David", "Luke", "Kate", "Bobby", "Megan"]
sentences = ["Megan is my friend", "Boddy is my friend"]

existed_name = [name for name in names for sentence in sentences if name in sentence]
```